# Delete All Files Matching Pattern In Directory

Tags: linux, grep

How can I delete all files containing `-20` in the filename in the current directory?

I have

```
ls | grep "-20" | rm -rf
```

But that does not work. Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rm -- *-20*
```

The -- stops -20 being treated as an argument to rm if the file -20 exists.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with

```
ls | grep "-20" | rm -rf  # DOESN'T WORK
```

is that you're piping filenames to `rm` but `rm` doesn't read from standard input.  You need to use `xargs` to call `rm` repeatedly like:

```
ls | grep '-20' | xargs rm -rf
```

But really, you don't want to use `ls | grep` to find file names.  Use the `find` command.

```
find . -name '*-20' | xargs rm -rf
```

But of course as the other poster said, the best solution is to `rm -- *-20*`.